# Use jquery to replace text in my cart

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace shipping text in my cart. The code below doesn't work.

```
    $("span#shippingOptions > label" ).replaceText("1-Day", "5-Day");
```

The html

```
    <span id="shippingOptions">
    <label for="shippingOptions_0" class="shippingLabel">Priority Mail 1-Day ($7.75)</label></span>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) jQuery method and JavaScript [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```js
$("span#shippingOptions > label" ).text($("span#shippingOptions > label" ).text().replace("1-Day", "5-Day"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="shippingOptions">
    <label for="shippingOptions_0" class="shippingLabel">Priority Mail 1-Day ($7.75)</label></span>
```

Comment: Yep but in the cart code it doesn't work.  I added it to the <head></head> as <script>$("span#shippingOptions > label" ).text($("span#shippingOptions > label" ).text().replace("1-Day", "5-Day"));</script> but doesn't work.

Comment: @alexma are you sure you have connected jQuery and code executes after DOM is ready?

Comment: Not sure what that means. I'm a beginner.

Comment: I have the code in the <head></head> not under the html.  I can't add it like you have it. I can only add it to the <head> and I don't have <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> < I can't add this it mess' up with everything.

Comment: Without adding jQuery your code will not work. You can add `<script>` part into head, but you should wrap javascript into `$(function() { ... your code here ... })`

Comment: I added this >  $(function() {$("span#shippingOptions > label" ).text($("span#shippingOptions > label" ).text().replace("1-Day", "5-Day")); })  but doesn't work.  Maybe it's because the page doesn't load?  I add the city, state, zip, and it processes and displays the shipping options.  There is other jQuery in the code... and it works.

Comment: They are using jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: jquery-ui != jquery. jQuery should be also added before that script run.

Comment: Like this -  jquery-ui != jquery $(function() {$("span#shippingOptions > label" ).text($("span#shippingOptions > label" ).text().replace("1-Day", "5-Day")); })

Comment: @alexma I mean that `jquery-ui` is not the same as `jquery`. jquery should be also added and it should be added before `<script>` tag where your script executes

Comment: So problem is elsewhere. As you can see in my example my code works. You need to look other places. Open console and look if there are any errors, etc.

Comment: I used other text on that page that's not dynamic and it works.  Since this text is coming from the post office xml, that must be the problem.

Comment: @alexma yeah, probably. So you need to run that script _after_ text appended from xml

Comment: @alexma it can be done even in head, but it's almost impossible to say how without seeing an example.

Comment: @example of website you are working on and how and when it's populated with data from xml, etc.

Comment: @alexma it says nothing to me. I can't help you without seeing the problem. Sorry.

Comment: How would you write your code if it ran when clicking on the page?

Comment: @alexma `$(document).on( 'click', function() { ...code... } );`

Answer (score 0):

Ohh.. You went wrong...

```
var curr = $("span#shippingOptions > label" );    
curr.text(curr.text().replace("1-Day", "5-Day"));
```